# spring + jpa = QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Учусь работать с JPA.
Есть MySQL таблица с полями a,b,c,d,e

spring-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
               "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru"/>

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

CdrItem.Class

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = CdrItem.GET_ALL, query = "SELECT i.a, i.b, i.c FROM CdrItem i")})

@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class CdrItem {
    public static final String GET_ALL = "CdrItem.getAll";

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "a", nullable = false)
//    @NotNull
    private String a;

    @Column(name = "b", nullable = false)
//    @NotBlank
    private String b;

    @Column(name = "c", nullable = false)
//    @NotBlank
    private String c;

    public CdrItem(String a, String b, String c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public CdrItem() {
    }
далее геттеры и сеттеры
...
}
```

interface JpaRepository.class

```
public interface JpaRepository {
    List<CdrItem> getAll();
}
```

JpaRepositoryImpl.Class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JpaRepositoryImpl implements JpaRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<CdrItem> geAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery(CdrItem.GET_ALL, CdrItem.class).getResultList();
    }

}
```

и когда я вызываю getAll(), я получаю:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
CdrItem.getAll failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped [SELECT i.a, i.b, i.c FROM table i]
```

Я не пойму, что не так... не видно таблицы table или не может найти записи, удовлетворяющие select'у ?

Comment: Почему у вас имя таблицы `i`, если оно должно быть `CdrItem`?

Comment: имя таблицы у меня table

Comment: Да, `table`, извиняюсь, но это не отменяет моего замечания.

Comment: Я наверное не до конца понимаю синтаксис SELECT'а в namedquery? Я делаю SELECT i.a, i.b, i.c FROM table i, т.е. я подразумеваю что в обычном mysql запросе это = select a,b,c from table... в namedQuery i это идентификатор-псевдоним таблицы table

Comment: У вас таблица называется `CdrItem`, потому что у вас стоит аннотация `Entity` и отсутствует аннотация `Table`, в которой указывается имя таблицы в БД. И ошибка вам явно говорит о том, что таблицы, с таким именем у вас в сущностях как бы нет. Вам нужно изменить в запросе имя таблицы на `CdrItem`, чтобы было так: `SELECT ... FROM CdrItem i ...`

Comment: Ага, понял. Но таблица у меня называется table... поэтому я поставил SELECT ... FROM CdrItem i ..., и добавил аннотацию к классу @Table(name = "table")

Comment: Теперь у меня выдает ошибку `Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [ru.CdrItem]`

Comment: Я отредактировал класс CdrItem.Class

Comment: Не могу понять что теперь не так?

Comment: так попробуйте - SELECT i FROM CdrItem i

Comment: так он ругается `IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [a], expecting one of []`

Comment: Всем спасибо за полезные ответы.
Разобрался. Заработало.